# Combining global object with another object using Object.assing, not being able to access the concatinated objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, concatenation

I have a lot of things I'm trying to set into the global variable in node.js. I tried doing something among the lines of...

```
global.awesomeFunc = (num1, num2) => {
    if (num1 == 9 && num2 == 10) return 21;
    return num1 + num2;
}
global.otherCoolFunc = () => {return 27 / 0;}
```

But, I realized I was taking up a lot of space just by constantly declaring `global` for each thing. So I looked up on concatenation and thought I could just set all my stuff in an object, then con-cat it with the global variable like:

```
let utils = {
    awesomeFunc: (num1, num2) => {/*You get my point...*/},
    otherCoolFunc: () => {return 27 / 0;}
}
global = Object.assign(utils, global);
```

But after that now I can't use `awesomeFunc` and `otherCoolFunc` without having to declare `global` before it? By using `global.awesomeFunc` I could run the function without `global`, but using concat I have to use `global.awesomeFunc`... Is there anyway I can regain the ability to use `awsomeFunc` without `global` while using `Object.assign`?

Comment: "taking up a lot of space just by constantly declaring `global`" — no, that doesn't take up space. However, loading up the global namespace is generally considered a bad practice. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to be able to use these variables and functions in another module using `require` by placing them in the `global` variable... Would there be another way?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Object.assign(target, ...sources)
>
> Parameters
>
> **target**
>       The target object.
>
> **sources**
>       The source object(s).
>
> Return value
>
> The **target** object.

when doing `global = Object.assign(utils, global);` you'll have `utils` with the properties of `global` in the `global` object,

reverse the `source` and the `target` :

`global = Object.assign(global, utils);` so you keep the old global with the properties of `utils`